# UK visitor visa - Cash inflow in account

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Me and wife are planning travel to UK for tourism. We both are financially independent and have required documents to provide evidence of ties to home country and necessary financial capability.

In my wife's account statement, there are entries of regular salary which we stated in application form but in one particular month of last 6 months, the company paid the yearly bonus, so the amount is more than double than regular salary in that month.The entry in statement clearly states company's name(a reputed MNC) and that it is salary, but do we need to write a covering letter and specifically mention the reason why the amount is higher in one month?

Also, this month is 4-5 months back, not recent. Since we will be providing salary slips as well, the salary entry for that month will be matching with salary slip which will have the bonus amount included. So logically I don't see need to explicitly call out a perfectly legal entry, but still seeking guidance.

Comment: It is hard to predict what staff will do but what harm could it do to explain it as you have done here? They must be very familiar with salary bonuses.

Answer (score 2):

It will be of good, to write a cover letter why the chunk of money and well detailed source, it doesn’t matter if it is months back, long as it’s included in the financial statement you will be sumbbiting then it’s necessary

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my case was similar, In my case some salaries were missing, because I received them when I was in Europe in hand. I explained my bank statement in detail in my cover letter. And I got the UK Visitor Visa.